# strange ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, indexoutofboundsexception

I have encountered a very strange exception. It runs well in here, but my customers keep encounter this exception and then crash, It have taken me many hours to figure it out, but unfortunately still no luck so far, any help will be appreciated!

This is the code:

```
protected void onPostExecute(List<File> result) {
    try {
        mBooks.clear();
        if (result != null) {
            ArrayList<BookInfo> newBooks = new ArrayList<BookInfo>();
            for (File f : result) {
                BookInfo bi = new BookInfo(BookCollections.this, f);
                if (!contains(bi)) {
                    newBooks.add(bi);
                }
            }
            mDB.insertBooks(newBooks);
            mBooks.addAll(newBooks);
            new AlertDialog.Builder(BookCollections.this)
                    .setTitle(newBooks.size() + " Books found!")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                    .setView(
            new BookInfoList(BookCollections.this,
            newBooks)).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        mScanDlg.dismiss();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

private boolean contains(BookInfo bi) {
    if (bi == null) {
        return true;
    }
    for (BookInfo book : mBooks) {
        if (book.equalTo(bi)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    for (FolderInfo fi : mFolders) {
        if (fi.getBooks() != null) {
            for (BookInfo book : fi.getBooks()) {
                if (book.equalTo(bi)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Please help me. Thanks

This exception(java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) raise up between

```
for (File f : result) {
    BookInfo bi = new BookInfo(BookCollections.this, f);
    if (!contains(bi)) {
        newBooks.add(bi);
    }
}
```

Comment: add extensive logging or invent a way to get the call stack of when this happens...

Comment: You say that it works well in here. What's here? Have you recreated the issue? If so can you post the logcat output for the calltrace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed your method name is onPostExecute.  Could this be a method which handles a web request?  If so, then when your customer runs this code, it may be running in a multi-threaded web container.  However, your collection, [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), is not a thread-safe collection.  This may be why it works in your development (single-threaded) environment but not on a busy server.

Consider using [Collections.synchronizedList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29) method to instantiate your ArrayList.  Be sure to follow the advice in the API docs on iterating within a synchronize block.

Comment: I doubted it was caused by multi-thread at first, I checked all the places I use the mBooks and mFolders, all of them are in UI thread. And I tried :
    protected void onPostExecute(List<File> result) {
    if (result != null) {
     List<File> lst = Collections.synchronizedList(result);
     ArrayList<BookInfo> newBooks = new ArrayList<BookInfo>();
     for (File f : lst) {
      
It still failed.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't read your code closely enough the first time.  You indicated the trouble occurs when you iterate over the collection passed as an input argument.  I was commenting on the wrong thing (ArrayList<BookInfo>).  It seems that List<File> collection may be changing out from under you.  Is the Android runtime passing that to you?  (I don't know enough about Android to know this).  If you can reproduce this, add a try-catch block to catch the exception and print the message.  It would be interesting to see what index causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The same strange behaviour i have faced before a few days in which emulator app shows perfact data but in device it shows an error same concept as of an Arraylist my suggestion is from your **PostExecute**   remove this line if u have not added before this any content in ArrayList **mBooks**

```
mBooks.clear();  // remove this line
```

and build and clean your project it works for u have faced same issue with different arraylist and sort out this way

yes you are right your error comes at this

```
 for (File f : result) {
                        BookInfo bi = new BookInfo(BookCollections.this, f);
                        if (!contains(bi)) {
                            newBooks.add(bi);
                        }
                    }
```

first check your arraylist size in Log as

```
   Log.d("Size",""+newBooks.size());
```

if it is greater than 0 than it feels ur array and one more thing is

change your method **contains**  bcz accroding to your **if** condition data is inserted in **newBooks** array when return data by **contains** method is **false** i think you are always getting boolean value **true**  so for that check

in Log as

```
Log.d("BooleanValue",""+newBooks.size());
```

before this    **if (!contains(bi))** condtion from log output you are able to see data is inserted in Arraylist or Not according to Condition Satisfied

Comment: Hi Khan, When the exception occurred, there was no such line:mBooks.clear();, I added this after that for debugging. Sorry for that. Does that line matter? The mBooks arraylist already has something in before this, that's why I check if there is duplicate item with if (!contains(bi)) {

Answer (score 0):

This is eventually found to be an ordinary `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` which is generated in

```
BookInfo bi = new BookInfo(BookCollections.this, f);
```

because there is another for clause that has an index that exceeds the boundary.

Answer (score 0):

1. As you have "mBooks.clear();" in the first line of onPoseExecute(), the statements

   ```
   for (BookInfo book : mBooks) {  
       if (book.equalTo(bi)) {  
           return true;  
       }  
   }
   ```

   in `contains()` seems to make no sense.
2. Are you sure the books related with "FoldInfo fi" will not be changed outside?

   ```
   for (FolderInfo fi : mFolders) {  
           if (fi.getBooks() != null) {  
               for (BookInfo book : fi.getBooks()) {  
                   if (book.equalTo(bi)) {  
                       return true;  
                   }  
               }  
           }  
       }
   ```

   I think the below codes could be better:

   ```
   for (FolderInfo fi : mFolders) {  
       ArrayList<BookInfo> books = fi.getBooks();  
       if (books  != null) {  
           for (BookInfo book : books) {  
               if (book.equalTo(bi)) {  
                   return true;  
               }  
           }  
       }  
   }
   ```
3. As you are using an AsyncTask and some codes(not this postexecute) are running in different threads, it's better to consider using some locks to protect your `mBooks`, `mFolders` and maybe `mDB`.